# How to arbitrarily stretch braces

Tags: scaling, braces

I want to stretch the `\rbrace` command by an arbitrary vertical scale factor in order to have precise control over its size inside a TikZ picture. Surely there's a simply command to stretch it, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat.

1. The top one is just an `\rbrace`, that does not stretch.
2. When used in an equation as part of the `\left. ...\right\}` syntax, it can stretch, but it will insist on stretching symmetrically about the math axis, and so it may not align with the content, if it is not vertically symmetrical
3. The `scalerel` package allows one to scale or stretch a glyph to fit the size of something specified, or to a numerical size.  In this case, it is scaled directly tot he size of the `\rule`.  The `\rule` can be hidden by using `\scalerel*{\}}{\rule...}` or `\scaleto{\}}{10ex}`.
4. Here is a variant of 3., in which the maximum width of the scale is limited to 1.5ex
5. This one is very versatile.  It is an extensible brace, originally horizontal, which I rotated vertically.  It fills the box of whatever size you place it in (its one deficiency is that it cannot shrink below a certain minimum size).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
$\rule[-2ex]{1ex}{5ex}\rbrace$

$\left.\rule[-5ex]{1ex}{10ex}\right\rbrace$

\scaleleftright{.}{\rule[-1ex]{1ex}{10ex}}{\rbrace}

\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{.}{\rule[-1ex]{1ex}{10ex}}{\rbrace}

\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[10ex]{\upbracefill}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've gone with the last, the minor drawback you mentioned doesn't affect me so its perfect. Thanks for that.