# delimeter not extending enough in relation to the denominator of a major fraction containing itself an extensible delimeter and a minor fraction

Tags: brackets, fractions, nesting

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  A1 &= \left\{\frac{1}{2\omega} \right. \\
     & \enspace \left. \left[\frac{z_{v}^2}{\left(\omega + \frac{z_{v}^2}{\omega}\right) t_{v}\left(z_{v}\right)}\right]\right\} \\
  A2 &= ...\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Now, the problem is that the rectangular brackets do not completely surround the larger inner curvy brackets in the major fraction denominator (themselves containing a minor fraction). Similarly, the outer curly brackets do not completely surround the rectangular brackets surrounding the major fraction. Is there a relatively straightforward way to automatically extend those rectangular brackets to surround the larger curvy brackets in the major fraction denominator and to extend the curly brackets just enough to surround the rectangular brackets?

I tried to use the usual `\bigl`-`\bigr`, `\biggl`-`\biggr`, `\Bigl`-`\Bigr`, and `\Biggl`-`\Biggr` combinations, but they are not large enough. I also tried to use vphantom, but that is too ad-hoc for my taste. I was looking for something cleaner. In principle, the `\left`-`\right` combination should work. Maybe that `\frac` command is preventing the left rectangular delimeter from gaining access to the extended delimeters in the major fraction denominator. Not sure. If there is no `\left`-`\right`-based solution available, I might need to set `\vastl`-`\vastr` and `\Vastl`-`\Vastr` commands as in this example: [mathtools brackets larger than \Bigg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262061/mathtools-brackets-larger-than-bigg;) but, if possible, I want to avoid that and stick to a `\left`-`\right`-based solution. The `\left(\rule{0cm}{2cm}\right.` approach could be an option, but I have equations with brackets opening in one line and closing in another. Not sure how to break sets of brackets across lines with `\left(\rule{0cm}{2cm}\right.`. Any help would be very welcome!

[image]

UPDATE:
**@Mico/@Werner**: I just extended the original MWE to a multiline equation with a shorter major fraction (and a shorter left rectangular bracket) on the first line and a taller major fraction (and a taller right rectangular bracket) on the second line, whereby said equation is part of several within the broader align and split environments I use. I can of course use fixed size brackets like `\Biggl`-`\Biggr`, but they cannot adequately surround the inner curvy brackets surrounding the minor fraction in the denominator of the major fraction in the second line. That is the actual problem!

Comment: Please don't down vote posts without explaining how they can be improved!

Comment: Which of [these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDKBJ.png) do you prefer?

Comment: **@Werner**: thanks a lot for the help! Well, I would prefer the one on the left-hand side, but ideally with the term in the numerator also vertically centered (right now only the term in the denominator looks vertically centered to me). Still, I would be interested in having both codes, since I need to harmonize quite long equations, and the solution on the right-hand side might unexpectedly become useful.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of extending your code snippet into an actual, i.e., compilable MWE. Feel free to revert.

Comment: **@Mico**: no problem! I am engaged in multiple fronts and wanted to have this issue addressed as soon as possible, so I wrote text and code a bit in a rush. My sincere apologies for that!

Comment: **@Mico**: yes, I had written that minor fraction inline as well in a desperate attempt to shorten those inner curly brackets in the denominator of the major fraction, but I have all my other fractions in the much broader equations I wrote **not inline**, so I wanted to stay consistent there. As I said, both codes may be useful. There is a certain level of uncertainty still from where I stand.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't overuse `\left` and `\right`. Even if you decide to do nothing else, please change `t_{v}\left(z_{v}\right` to `t_{v}(z_{v})` in order to fix the wretched spacing between `t_{v}` and `(z_{v})`.

Comment: **@Mico**: thanks again for the recommendation. I just do this to be on the safe side so to say and make sure that those brackets are always correctly sized in relation to one another. It can be tricky when you have really long and complex mathematical expressions with large numbers of brackets. I was not aware of that spacing issue though. Will correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @Euclides - It is decidedly not the case that parentheses and brackets autosized via `\left` and `\right` "are always correctly sized". Sometimes they're too small, sometimes they're too large. For more information on this see, e.g., [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001)

Comment: **@Mico/@Werner**: I just extended the original MWE to a multiline equation with a shorter major fraction (and a shorter left rectangular bracket) on the first line and a taller major fraction (and a taller right rectangular bracket) on the second line, whereby said equation is part of several within the broader align and split environments I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments regarding your setup:

- Think about using some space to spread out your constructions so it's easier to see the grouping of elements.
- Use [Left/Right across multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764) to spread a large construction across a multi-line equation structure. For this, the suggested solution is to use a `\vphantom` to spread the brackets in locations it doesn't have sufficient height.
- Superficial stretching of `\left`/`\right` delimiters can be achieved with a strut - `\rule[<height/depth>]{0pt}{0pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  A1 &= \left\{ 
          \vphantom{
            \left[
              \frac
                {z_v^2}
                {\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}
                  \left(\omega + \frac{z_v^2}{\omega}\right) t_v (z_v)}
            \right]
          }
          \dfrac{1}{2 \omega} 
        \right. \\
     & \qquad 
        \left.
          \left[
            \frac
              {z_v^2}
              {\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}
                \left(\omega + \frac{z_v^2}{\omega}\right) t_v (z_v)}
          \right]
        \right\} \\
  A2 &= \ldots
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **@Werner**: thanks a lot! This is almost perfect. I say almost, because we still have that empty space above the term in the numerator, I guess because `\left` and `\right` always center the fraction bar. I tried to use the same strut with `\biggl` and `\biggr` (which do not center the fraction bar), but the bracket won't extend. Is there any solution for this? If this is solved, then I will almost certainly upvote your answer. I prepared a version with inline fractions as suggested by @Mico, and it looks good, except that it costs me one extra bracket type, which I need for my expressions.

Comment: **@Werner**: obviously the strut won't work with `\biggl` and `\biggr` as these are non extensible brackets. Perhaps this ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169172/how-to-arbitrarily-stretch-braces)) approach could be useful? Not sure.

Comment: @Euclides: If you're wanting to reduce the empty space above the numerator you won't have the braces on the vertical center. For this, review [How to get uneven size/space of numerator and denominator in fraction enclosed by `\left\{` and `\right}` brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472540/5764).

Comment: **@Werner**: those uneven braces would be interesting, but would require quite extensive programming, especially with my multiline equations. I think I can live with that space above the numerator, for now. In any case, I will work in more detail on versions with display or inline fractions and see how those look like, before finally upvoting an answer (latest in about 12 hours), Thanks a lot for your help Werner!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a third option to complement @Werner's two options: An all-inline-fraction solution. It's shown on the left in the following screenshot, along with my own interpretation of one of @Werner's options; note that I don't use `\left[` and `\right]` as I don't want to force LaTeX to place the fraction's horizontal line in in the middle of the space created by the square brackets.

[image]

If the `\Big` symbols are too big for your taste, you could always switch to `\big`.

Inline-style fraction notation has been around for at least a couple of centuries. Don't underestimate your readers' ability to understand it right away. Compared with `\frac` notation, one of its main advantages is that the symbols don't ever become very small.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
%% all-inline-fraction notation
\Bigl\{
z_{v}^2 \Big/ \Bigl[(\omega + z_{v}^2/\omega)\, t_{v}(z_{v})\Bigr]
\Bigr\}
\qquad
%% my interpretation of one of @Werner's suggestions
\left\{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{z_{v}^2}{\bigl(\omega + \frac{z_{v}^2}{\omega}\bigr)
  t_{v}(z_{v})}
  \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: **@Mico**: thanks a lot! I will prepare a version of my (multiple) multiline (roughly 4 line) equations with only inline fractions and see how that looks like. Still, I would be grateful if I could access Werner's solution for display fractions with correctly sized nested brackets.

Comment: @Euclides - I've edited my answer to include code with my own interpretation of how to code one of Werner's solution suggestions.

Comment: **@Mico**: interesting approach. I might try to add yet another matrix layer with curly brackets. Just to see if the inner matrix is better surrounded by the outer matrix. But as it is this already is an improvement. However, I have rectangular brackets starting in one line and ending in another, and I guess the matrix cannot start in one line and end in another, without affecting bracket sizes, or can it?

Comment: @Euclides - Replacing `\left\{ ... \end\}` in the second solution with `\begin{Bmatrix} ... \end{Bmatrix}` won't change the result. About your guess: A single matrix-like environment cannot span several lines. Neither can `\left` in one row and `\right` in another.

Comment: **@Mico**: absolutely! Question: is there an equation linebreak set of commands for `\begin{Bmatrix}-\end{Bmatrix}` that's equivalent to the `\right. \\ ` and `\left. ` ones used for `\left`-`\right`?

Comment: **@Mico**: I guess I would need to look deeper into `\Bmatrix` to understand how those brackets are actually constructed. Anyway, I will now test the all inline approach. See how that looks like. I agree it has many advantages, but one big disadvantage is that it makes long equations even longer, especially if you have many many fractions; so, in my case I may have 6-line equations rather than 4-line (spanning the standard width of A4 page minus equation label width, roughly speaking).

Comment: **@Mico**: one more question. What would be a good alternative to `\Bmatrix` that would yield the same results? I guess the only way is to define those `\vastl`-`\vastr` or `Vastl`-`Vastr` sets of commands as in the example I mentioned in my original question, right? Also, I read that `\Bmatrix` is based on `\left`-`\right`, so maybe I could find something in the definition of `\Bmatrix`.

Comment: **@Mico**: I will have a version of my multiline, multibracket equations with only inline fractions ready, just to be on the safe side; while I/ we try to find a good solution for multiline, multibracket equations with only display fractions. I will also probably update the MWE to an actual multiline equation, so that the complete problem can be fully addressed.

Comment: @Euclides - Yes, posting a representative equation would be helpful.